# How to concatenate the mark tag to individual words in a string using the replace function?

Tags: javascript

The  following function tries to concatenate the `<mark>` tag to elements of a string if found in the `knownWords`array. Thus after the code is executed the out put should be,

```
Marked string: The <mark>quick</mark> <mark>brown</mark> fox jumped over the <mark>lazy</mark> dog.
```

However, the string remains unchanged after execution.

```js
let knownWords = ["quick", "brown", "lazy"];

let string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';

console.log('Original string:', string);
knownWords.forEach(match);

function match(value) {
  string.replace(/value/g, '<mark>' + value + '</mark>');

}
console.log('Marked string: ',string);
```

Comment: `.replace` does not mutate the original string; primitives are immutable. Try reassigning instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-assign `string` to the result of `string.replace()` and use `RegExp` constructor with `value` passed as parameter, instead of the `RegExp` literal `/value/`

```js
let knownWords = ["quick", "brown", "lazy"];

let string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';

console.log('Original string:', string);
knownWords.forEach(match);

function match(value) {
  string = string.replace(new RegExp(`${value}`), '<mark>' + value + '</mark>');
}

console.log('Marked string: ', string);
```

Alternatively

```js
let knownWords = ["quick", "brown", "lazy"];

let string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';

console.log('Original string:', string);

string = string.replace(new RegExp(knownWords.join("|"), "g"), function(match) {
  return `<mark>${match}</mark>`
})

console.log('Marked string: ', string);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let knownWords = ["quick", "brown", "fox"];

let string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';

console.log('Original string:', string);
knownWords.forEach(match);

function match(value) {
  string.replace(/value/g, '<mellan>' + value + '</mellan>');

}
console.log('Marked string: ',string);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';

let knownWords = ["quick", "brown", "fox"];

console.log('Original string:', string);
knownWords.forEach(match);

function match(value) {
  string.replace(/value/g, '<mark>' + value + '</mark>');

}
console.log('Marked string: ',string);
```